# UIScreen.main.bounds wrong value on iphone X emulator

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone-x

I'm trying to adapt an app to run on the iPhone X's screen but the UIScreen.main.bounds.size is always returning 375x667 and it should return 375x815.

I am running on a iPhone X simulator and everything works fine, except for this, so I am having a hard time on positioning elements on the screen as the wrong height is read.

I forced the height to be 710 just to see how it behaves.
Take a look at the picture and you will observe 2 crazy things:

- The banner is cropped by the black area;
- The corners of the app are rounded even with the black stripes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Launch screen for iPhone X. Which size is `Portrait size    1125px × 2436px` & `Landscape size 2436px × 1125px`
Hope it helps!